# Convergence in L^2

Tags: analysis

> Define a function $f_\varepsilon: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as 
>   $$\begin{equation}
>     f_\varepsilon(x) =
>     \begin{cases}
>        -1 & \text{if}\; \,x<-\varepsilon \\
>        \sin \left(\frac{\pi x}{2 \varepsilon}\right) & \text{if}\;\, |x| \le \varepsilon\\
>       1       & \text{if}\;\, x>\varepsilon
>     \end{cases}
>   \end{equation} $$
>   Then $f_\varepsilon(x)$ converges pointwise to $\mbox{sgn}(x)$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$. And it can be easily proven that $ \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_\varepsilon(x)- \mbox{sgn}(x)|^2\,dx= C\varepsilon $ .

My question is given $u \in L^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\varphi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ can we prove $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_\varepsilon(u(x))- \mbox{sgn}(u(x))|^2\varphi(x)\,dx \le C\varepsilon^r$$ for some r>0.
I actually tried to mimic the proof but the main issue over here is we cannot apply the change of variable formula. And I'm always ending up in an upper bound like $\varepsilon^r+c$, which is not desired.

Comment: What would $\delta$ be?

Comment: If the fact you can't apply change of variable formula brothers you, I'd suggest try to prove it first for u smooth and then just approach your general function by smooth functions on the support of $\phi$.

Comment: @Mindlack I'm sorry that would be epsilon.

Comment: What then if $u=0$?

Comment: Then it is vacuously true

Comment: @Keen $u$ is required to be one-one to apply change of variable, which need not be true here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take, for every $0 < t < 1$, $u(t)=e^{-1/t}$ and $u=0$ everywhere else. Take $\varphi$ to be a smooth approximation of $1_{[0,1]}$, that is not lower than this function. On $[0,1]$, $\{0 < u \leq r\}$ has measure $|\ln{r}|^{-1}$.

Thus your integral is not lower than $\int_{0<|u| \leq \epsilon/2}{|1-sin(\pi/4)|^2} \geq \frac{c}{|\ln(\epsilon/2)|}$ where $c >0$ is a numeric constant. So the answer to your question is negative.

Comment: Why is the measure $|\log r|^{-1}$?

Comment: $0 <u(t) \leq r$ iff $0 < t < 1$ and $e^{-1/t} \leq r$ and you can figure out the rest.

Comment: But $e^{-1/t} \leq r$ gives $ t \ge -1/\log r$ if $r >1$ and $t< -1/ \log r$ if $r<1$.

Comment: But note that $r < 1$ always because $0 \leq u  \leq e^{-1}$.

Comment: And why does the last inequality contradicts?

Comment: When $r>0$ goes to $0$, then for any $a<0$, $|\ln(r)| << r^a$, so this integral is $>>\epsilon^{-a}$ for any $a <0$.